# How to differentiate between the pageload and button click method in asp.net MVC 4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and don't know how to differentiate between a page load event and a button click event; for example this is the scenario according to asp.net webform application;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //does something
        }
```

and button click is as follows;

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//does something
}
```

I have used so far in terms of MVC

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        //does something
        return View();
    }


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        //does something
        return View();
    }
```

I don't know except this. And it is obvious that IIS is giving ambiguity error as both have [HttpPost] attribute.
anyone know this, hope everyone except me, please advise me, thanks.

Comment: you should go through an mvc tutorial.  MVC doesn't have events like page load and btnLogin like you have them.  that is the web form way of doing things.  for a login view you have a HttpGet on the first one that will build the view model to be passed to the view (similar to a page load) the post would then be the login button click that does a postback